# golang static server always returns 404 page not found

Tags: http, go, webserver, raspberry-pi3

I try to get a Go webserver running on a raspberry pi (using 1.10.1)
I have a go webserver implemented like (StatPiPrivider.go):

```
package main

import (
        "net/http"
)

func main() {
        http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static/templates")))
        http.ListenAndServe(":3000", nil)
}
```

and the static folder is in the same folder as the StatPiProvider.go file.

In the folder static/templates are 4 html files including one index.html

Everytime I rewuest the server I get a response 404 page not found. Even if I try to get an other html-file I get the same response.

Is it a problem with my implementation or is something on my raspberry wrong.

I run the code with: go run StatPiProvider/StatPiProvider.go

Comment: when you use `./static/templates` it is a relative path from the current working directory, depends where the process started it may not be where you think it is... how about use the absolute path and see if that works.

Comment: `go run` will run at tmp folder. U should use `go build && ./StatPiProvider`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that `go run` does not change the working directory. So any relative path you use in your app, they will be resolved to the working directory, the folder from which you run `go run`.

Since the `static` folder is next to the `StatPiProvider.go` file, and you use the path `./static/templates`, their containing folder must be the working directory when you run `go run`.

So first change dir so the `StatPiProvider.go` will be in the working directory, and then launch the `.go` file like this:

```
cd StatPiProvider
go run StatPiProvider.go
```